# JSLint - Do not mutate parameter <x> when using 'arguments'?

Tags: javascript, parameters, jslint

All,

I use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to validate my JS files. In my most recent project, I am using the following format to set default values for a number of JavaScript functions (further detailed [here](http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-is-dead-long-live-javascript)):

```
function(a, b, option) {
    option = arguments.length > 2 ? option : "some default value";
    // ...
}
```

This however causes the latest build of JSLint to produce the following error:

```
"Do not mutate parameter 'option' when using 'arguments'."
```

I am aware that using the more common method for assigning defaults (i.e., `option = option || {};`) supresses the error; however, this will produce incorrect behaviour if I intend to pass a *falsey* value to `option`.

Is the only solution to this issue to introduce a new variable? e.g.:

```
var option2 = arguments.length > 2 ? option : "some default value";
```

Comment: A local variable, which is your "introduce a second parameter" is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess JSLint warns you since you try to modify one of the input arguments by using a check with the arguments keyword. [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), however, does give me any warning when trying your code.

A solution to your problem would be to check if `option` is defined or not, that way you go around the problem with sending in falsy values:

```
function(a, b, option) {
    if(typeof option === "undefined") {
        option = "some default value"; 
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you find that it is cumbersome to write this `typeof` check everytime, create an `isDef` function:

```
function isDef(param) {
    return typeof param !== "undefined";
}
function(a, b, option) {
    option = isDef(option) ? option : "some default value"; 
    // ...
}
```

// Simon A.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - removing the risk of specifying an incorrect value for `arguments.length` is a big plus. Unfortunately, using this method causes JSLint to produce the the same error.

Comment: Are you sure? JSLint doesn't complain when I run the two code snippets above.

Comment: Turns out we can both be right, depending on the situation. In my code, I have a function with two parameters requiring defaults to be set. I was using your solution only on the first one (for testing purposes), leaving the second still using the `arguments` variable. This caused JSLint to raise the error against *both* parameters - very strange!

Answer (score 0):

In most situations you'd be better off just doing:

```
function(a, b, option) {
    option = option || "some default value";
    // ...
}
```

or

```
function(a, b, option) {
    if ( !option || typeof option !== 'string' ) { 
        option = "some default value";
    }
    // ...
}
```